# When ı compile yolov3 ı get take warnings

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing

```
"""YOLO v3 output
"""
 import numpy as np
 import keras.backend as K
 from keras.models import load_model
 import os

 class YOLO:
       def __init__(self, obj_threshold, nms_threshold):
         """Init.

    # Arguments
        obj_threshold: Integer, threshold for object.
        nms_threshold: Integer, threshold for box.
    """
    self._t1 = obj_threshold
    self._t2 = nms_threshold
    self._yolo = load_model('data/yolo.h5')  
def _process_feats(self, out, anchors, mask):
    """process output features.

    # Arguments
        out: Tensor (N, N, 3, 4 + 1 +80), output feature map of yolo.
        anchors: List, anchors for box.
        mask: List, mask for anchors.

    # Returns
        boxes: ndarray (N, N, 3, 4), x,y,w,h for per box.
        box_confidence: ndarray (N, N, 3, 1), confidence for per box.
        box_class_probs: ndarray (N, N, 3, 80), class probs for per box.
    """
    grid_h, grid_w, num_boxes = map(int, out.shape[1: 4])

    anchors = [anchors[i] for i in mask]
    # Reshape to batch, height, width, num_anchors, box_params.
    anchors_tensor = K.reshape(K.variable(anchors),
                               [1, 1,len(anchors), 2])
    out = out[0]
    box_xy = K.get_value(K.sigmoid(out[..., :2]))
    box_wh = K.get_value(K.exp(out[..., 2:4]) * anchors_tensor)
    box_confidence = K.get_value(K.sigmoid(out[..., 4]))
    box_confidence = np.expand_dims(box_confidence, axis=-1)
    box_class_probs = K.get_value(K.sigmoid(out[..., 5:]))

    col = np.tile(np.arange(0, grid_w), grid_w).reshape(-1, grid_w)
    row = np.tile(np.arange(0, grid_h).reshape(-1, 1), grid_h)

    col = col.reshape(grid_h, grid_w, 1, 1).repeat(3, axis=-2)
    row = row.reshape(grid_h, grid_w, 1, 1).repeat(3, axis=-2)
    grid = np.concatenate((col, row), axis=-1)

    box_xy += grid
    box_xy /= (grid_w, grid_h)
    box_wh /= (416, 416)
    box_xy -= (box_wh / 2.)
    boxes = np.concatenate((box_xy, box_wh), axis=-1)

    return boxes, box_confidence, box_class_probs

def _filter_boxes(self, boxes, box_confidences, box_class_probs):
    """Filter boxes with object threshold.

    # Arguments
        boxes: ndarray, boxes of objects.
        box_confidences: ndarray, confidences of objects.
        box_class_probs: ndarray, class_probs of objects.

    # Returns
        boxes: ndarray, filtered boxes.
        classes: ndarray, classes for boxes.
        scores: ndarray, scores for boxes.
    """
    box_scores = box_confidences * box_class_probs
    box_classes = np.argmax(box_scores, axis=-1)
    box_class_scores = np.max(box_scores, axis=-1)
    pos = np.where(box_class_scores >= self._t1)

    boxes = boxes[pos]
    classes = box_classes[pos]
    scores = box_class_scores[pos]

    return boxes, classes, scores

def _nms_boxes(self, boxes, scores):
    """Suppress non-maximal boxes.

    # Arguments
        boxes: ndarray, boxes of objects.
        scores: ndarray, scores of objects.

    # Returns
        keep: ndarray, index of effective boxes.
    """
    x = boxes[:, 0]
    y = boxes[:, 1]
    w = boxes[:, 2]
    h = boxes[:, 3]

    areas = w * h
    order = scores.argsort()[::-1]

    keep = []
    while order.size > 0:
        i = order[0]
        keep.append(i)

        xx1 = np.maximum(x[i], x[order[1:]])
        yy1 = np.maximum(y[i], y[order[1:]])
        xx2 = np.minimum(x[i] + w[i], x[order[1:]] + w[order[1:]])
        yy2 = np.minimum(y[i] + h[i], y[order[1:]] + h[order[1:]])

        w1 = np.maximum(0.0, xx2 - xx1 + 1)
        h1 = np.maximum(0.0, yy2 - yy1 + 1)
        inter = w1 * h1

        ovr = inter / (areas[i] + areas[order[1:]] - inter)
        inds = np.where(ovr <= self._t2)[0]
        order = order[inds + 1]

    keep = np.array(keep)

    return keep

def _yolo_out(self, outs, shape):
    """Process output of yolo base net.

    # Argument:
        outs: output of yolo base net.
        shape: shape of original image.

    # Returns:
        boxes: ndarray, boxes of objects.
        classes: ndarray, classes of objects.
        scores: ndarray, scores of objects.
    """
    masks = [[6, 7, 8], [3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2]]
    anchors = [[10, 13], [16, 30], [33, 23], [30, 61], [62, 45],
               [59, 119], [116, 90], [156, 198], [373, 326]]

    boxes, classes, scores = [], [], []

    for out, mask in zip(outs, masks):
        b, c, s = self._process_feats(out, anchors, mask)
        b, c, s = self._filter_boxes(b, c, s)
        boxes.append(b)
        classes.append(c)
        scores.append(s)

    boxes = np.concatenate(boxes)
    classes = np.concatenate(classes)
    scores = np.concatenate(scores)

    # Scale boxes back to original image shape.
    width, height = shape[1], shape[0]
    image_dims = [width, height, width, height]
    boxes = boxes * image_dims

    nboxes, nclasses, nscores = [], [], []
    for c in set(classes):
        inds = np.where(classes == c)
        b = boxes[inds]
        c = classes[inds]
        s = scores[inds]

        keep = self._nms_boxes(b, s)

        nboxes.append(b[keep])
        nclasses.append(c[keep])
        nscores.append(s[keep])

    if not nclasses and not nscores:
        return None, None, None

    boxes = np.concatenate(nboxes)
    classes = np.concatenate(nclasses)
    scores = np.concatenate(nscores)

    return boxes, classes, scores

def predict(self, image, shape):
    """Detect the objects with yolo.

    # Arguments
        image: ndarray, processed input image.
        shape: shape of original image.

    # Returns
        boxes: ndarray, boxes of objects.
        classes: ndarray, classes of objects.
        scores: ndarray, scores of objects.
    """

    outs = self._yolo.predict(image)
    boxes, classes, scores = self._yolo_out(outs, shape)

    return boxes, classes, scores
```

This is the yolo v3 code and when ı work main program ı take this error

```py
InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [13,13,2] vs. [1,1,3,2] [Op:Mul]
```

Main part is
import cv2
import numpy as np
from yolo_model import YOLO

```
    yolo = YOLO(0.6, 0.5)
    file = "data/coco_classes.txt"

     with open(file) as f:
     class_name = f.readlines()

      all_classes = [c.strip() for c in class_name]
       print("A")
      f = "dog_cat.jpg"
      path = "images/"+f
       image = cv2.imread(path)
      cv2.imshow("image",image)

      pimage = cv2.resize(image, (416,416))
      pimage = np.array(pimage, dtype = "float32")
      pimage /= 255.0
      pimage = np.expand_dims(pimage, axis = 0)

      # yolo
      boxes, classes, scores = yolo.predict(pimage, image.shape)

      for box, score, cl in zip(boxes, scores, classes):

       x,y,w,h = box

       top = max(0, np.floor(x + 0.5).astype(int))
       left = max(0, np.floor(y + 0.5).astype(int))
       right = max(0, np.floor(x + w + 0.5).astype(int))
       bottom = max(0, np.floor(y + h + 0.5).astype(int))

       cv2.rectangle(image, (top,left), (right, bottom),(255,0,0),2)
       cv2.putText(image, "{} {}".format(all_classes[cl],score),(top,left-6),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.6,               (0,0,255),1,cv2.LINE_AA)

       cv2.imshow("yolo",image)
```

I take problem in `box_wh = K.get_value(K.exp(out[..., 2:4]) * anchors_tensor)`. Is multiply necessary? And what do box_wh?

Comment: OpenCV actually comes with Yolo included. Would you be alright with using that instead of going through keras?

Comment: I'm sure because bos wanted me to do it with keras.